# C# expression to validate a Cron job

Tags: c#, cron

Whats the best way to validate something like this expression is a valid cron expression, (in C#)

```
“At 00:00 on Friday.”
Cron Expression passed in
0 0 * * FRI
```

Comment: What if the expression is valid, but it's incorrect? E.g. you wanted to "At 00:00 on Friday" but you got "0 0 1 * * FRI" which is valid but specifies only first day of the month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NCrontab.Advanced/

or using this reference:

https://quartznet.sourceforge.io/apidoc/2.0/html/

```
bool IsValid = IsValidSchedule("0 0 * * FRI");
```

Then:

```
   public static bool IsValidSchedule(string schedule) {
    
            var valid = CronExpression.IsValidExpression(schedule);
            // Some expressions are parsed as valid by the above method but they are not valid, like "* * * ? * *&54".
            //In order to avoid such invalid expressions an additional check is required, that is done using the below regex.
    
            var regex = @"^\s*($|#|\w+\s*=|(\?|\*|(?:[0-5]?\d)(?:(?:-|\/|\,)(?:[0-5]?\d))?(?:,(?:[0-5]?\d)(?:(?:-|\/|\,)(?:[0-5]?\d))?)*)\s+(\?|\*|(?:[0-5]?\d)(?:(?:-|\/|\,)(?:[0-5]?\d))?(?:,(?:[0-5]?\d)(?:(?:-|\/|\,)(?:[0-5]?\d))?)*)\s+(\?|\*|(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3])(?:(?:-|\/|\,)(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3]))?(?:,(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3])(?:(?:-|\/|\,)(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3]))?)*)\s+(\?|\*|(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(?:(?:-|\/|\,)(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))?(?:,(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(?:(?:-|\/|\,)(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))?)*)\s+(\?|\*|(?:[1-9]|1[012])(?:(?:-|\/|\,)(?:[1-9]|1[012]))?(?:L|W)?(?:,(?:[1-9]|1[012])(?:(?:-|\/|\,)(?:[1-9]|1[012]))?(?:L|W)?)*|\?|\*|(?:JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)(?:(?:-)(?:JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC))?(?:,(?:JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)(?:(?:-)(?:JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC))?)*)\s+(\?|\*|(?:[0-6])(?:(?:-|\/|\,|#)(?:[0-6]))?(?:L)?(?:,(?:[0-6])(?:(?:-|\/|\,|#)(?:[0-6]))?(?:L)?)*|\?|\*|(?:MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN)(?:(?:-)(?:MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN))?(?:,(?:MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN)(?:(?:-)(?:MON|TUE|WED|THU|FRI|SAT|SUN))?)*)(|\s)+(\?|\*|(?:|\d{4})(?:(?:-|\/|\,)(?:|\d{4}))?(?:,(?:|\d{4})(?:(?:-|\/|\,)(?:|\d{4}))?)*))$";
    
            return valid&& Regex.IsMatch(schedule, regex);
        }
```

Comment: This probably the most accepted method. But is there a way I could do this without using Quartz ?

Comment: @w2olves you didn't mention it at all in your question.

Comment: @Leanadro that is true. I mentioned C# and assumed it will not be a library recommendation. Thank you for this answer

Comment: Leandro Bardelli, I too go tired of bringing in bulky libraries just to manage CRON expressions.  Currently, I don't have a "IsValid" method, but you can retool the static ValidateExpression so it returns a boolean instead of throwing an exception.   See:  https://github.com/rashadrivera/CronExpression/blob/master/CronExpression/Internals/CronExpressionHelper.cs